# Unable to draw points on GeoGraphics

Tags: plotting, geographics

```mathematica
ycData = 
  Dataset[
    Import[
     "https://geo.datav.aliyun.com/areas_v3/bound/640100_full.json", 
     "RawJSON"]]["features", All];
hlxData = ycData[5, Key["geometry"], Key["coordinates"], 1];

hlxGeoPlt = Quiet@GeoGraphics[
   {
    EdgeForm[Black],
    FaceForm[Red],
    Polygon@Map[GeoPosition, Map[Reverse, Normal@hlxData, {2}], {2}]
    },
   
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> All,
   GeoRange -> Quantity[30, "Miles"],
   GeoBackground -> None,
   ImageSize -> 700,
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
     Black},
   GeoScaleBar -> {"Imperial", "Kilometers"}
   ]
```

get this

[image]

I want to draw some points on the map，like this

[image]

This is a schematic. I don't actually know the exact point, so I have to find it manually，I used a tool that comes with Wolfram and found a few points myself

[image]

by hand I have find some point .

```mathematica
(*by hand*)
path1 = {
    {106.3032, 41.98753},
    {106.3096, 41.99726},
    {106.3096, 41.99726},
    {106.3184, 42.00899},
    {106.3286, 42.01981},
    {106.3494, 42.04681},
    {106.3638, 42.06126},
    {106.3682, 42.0741},
    {106.4294, 42.12032}
    } /. {{x_, y_} -> {y, x}};
(*plot*)
pathGeoPlt = GeoGraphics[
  {Red,
   PointSize[.01],
   Point@GeoPosition@path1},
  GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image]

I tried to add the points I found to my starting point image, but failed！

[image]

How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you copied the data by hand from the plot, but you got the wrong set of coordinates for the points you chose by hand. Use the "Get Coordinates" tool to select points (right click on the plot), then click on the points of interest, and copy them to clipboard (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or equivalent in your system), move to a new insertion point and paste the selected points as `GeoCoordinates` objects (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or equivalent). See this clip:

[image: copy and paste from geographics]

Now you have a list of points:

```
handpath = {
   GeoPosition[{38.72612538228502, 106.33815314973353`}, "ITRF00"], 
   GeoPosition[{38.70174707024354, 106.304069768805}, "ITRF00"], 
   GeoPosition[{38.71615344136305, 106.19187863991533`}, "ITRF00"], 
   GeoPosition[{38.71836954848582, 106.07258680666554`}, "ITRF00"]};
```

With those, and simplifying your code a little:

```
hlxData = 
  Query["features", 5, "geometry", "coordinates", 1, 1, Map@Reverse]@
   Import["https://geo.datav.aliyun.com/areas_v3/bound/640100_full.json", "RawJSON"];

GeoGraphics[
  {
    {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Red], GeoPolygon[hlxData]},
    {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point@ handpath}
  },
  GeoGridRange -> All,
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, GeoRange -> Quantity[25, "Miles"], 
  GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 700, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Black}, 
  GeoScaleBar -> {"Imperial", "Kilometers"}
]
```

[image: plot of region and points within it]